# how to show editors-xtd buttons (image, toggle editor) in joomla

Tags: editor, joomla3.0, tinymce-4

I got a problem to display editors-xtd buttons (image, toggle editor) at the bottom of the editor. please help

```
tinymce.init({
            // General
            directionality: "ltr",
            language : "en",
            mode : "specific_textareas",
            strict_loading_mode : true,
            //autosave_restore_when_empty: false,
            skin : "lightgray",
                            theme : "modern",
            schema: "html5",
            invalid_elements : "javascript,iframe,applet",
            selector: "textarea.mce_editable",
            allow_script_urls: false,
                            plugins : "table link image hr charmap autolink lists importcss pagebreak paste code ",
                //responsivefilemanager     
            // Toolbar
            toolbar1: "bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | formatselect | bullist numlist ",
            toolbar2: " unlink link image  "})
```

Comment: The code above is what is generated by Joomla in order to launch TinyMCE ?  Did you try to configure xtd admin modules ?

Comment: I solved it already, I need to render the default editor (Joomla) in order to display all editors-xtd buttons instead of Initializing a editor by myself (buttons are disappeared). If you want to hide one of them, you should access to admin mode, go plugin manager, search their name, then you disable them. so that. it will not show it on the page.